# Jquery - Adding ID to href

Tags: jquery, html

I am a beginner with jQUERY.

I am trying to simply add an ID to the end of my href link, but when I add it everything stops working.

```
$(".galleryImg").wrap("<a href="'product.html?id=' + id + ">");
```

Would somebody advise me on what im doing wrong please?

Comment: Is `galleryImg` a list of nodes?

Comment: Check your quotes

Comment: Try This $('element').attr('id', 'value');

Comment: Pretty sure your quotes are even confusing themselves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(".galleryImg").wrap("<a href='product.html?id=" + id + "'></a>");
```

There was a mistake in your code. You endet the string here:

```
"<a href="
```

" ist not equal to '

Also end your HTML Tag as seen [here](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

```
$(".galleryImg").wrap("<a href="'product.html?id=' + id + ">");
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to this(what went wrong and how you corrected it) as it will benefit beginners a lot